# Prove that bn is also convergent and has a limit l.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[Question posed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ9lY.png)

The image is the question I've been stuck on for a few days now.

Answer (score 1):

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have :
$$ |b_n - l|  \le |b_n - a_n| + |a_n - l| = |a_n| \left| \frac {b_n}{a_n} - 1 \right | + |a_n - l| \le C \left| \frac {b_n}{a_n} - 1 \right | + |a_n - l|. $$
Indeed the sequence $(a_n)$ is convergent and therefore bounded i.e. there exists $C > 0$ such that $|a_n| \le C$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. You can probably conclude from here.

Comment: What would be the best way of concluding with this... I has discussion with tutor but he thinks my conclusion wasn't sufficient

Comment: Let $\varepsilon > 0$, because the sequence $\left (\frac {b_n} {a_n} \right)$ converges to $1$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N \implies \left | \frac {b_n} {a_n} - 1 \right | < \frac {\varepsilon} {2C}$. Similarly there exists $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > M \implies |a_n - l| < \frac \varepsilon 2$. If $L= \max\{N,M\}$ then $ n > L \implies |b_n - l| \le C  \left | \frac {b_n} {a_n} - 1 \right | + |a_n - l| <C\frac {\varepsilon}{2C} + \frac \varepsilon 2 = \varepsilon$ which by definition equivalent to saying the sequence $(b_n)$ converges to $l$.

Comment: My last comment comes back to the definition of a limit but if you have proven the sandwich theorem (not sure of the name in english) then see if you can use it ! (hint : you can)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $b_n \not\to l$. Then there exists an $\epsilon >0$ and a subsequence $\{b_{n_k}\}$ of $\{b_n\}$ such that $|b_{n_k} - l| \ge \epsilon$ for all $k$. But $a_n \to l$, so so does the sequence $a_{n_k}$. But then looking at our sequence $\displaystyle \frac{b_n}{a_n} \to 1$, this implies that any subsequence, including $\displaystyle \frac{b_{n_k}}{a_{n_k}}$ converges to $1$. But then $b_{n_k}$ converges to the same limit as $a_{n_k}$, and since $a_{n_k} \to l$, we have a contradiction.